# Wrong number of lanes via DisplayPort, probably Nvidia GTX 1080 driver issue

Tags: xorg, nvidia, gpu, multi-monitor, displayport

Suddenly one of three monitors (DELL U2414H) stopped working. In nvidia-settings I can see 4 lanes instead of 2.

It is the only visible difference between working and not working monitor configuration.

#### Working:

[image: Working]

#### Not working:

[image: Not working]

Sometimes, I have a similar issue with the wrong number of lanes, but 1 lane instead of 2. It happens after turning the monitor off and on, and is OS- and driver-independent. The only solution I found is re-plugging the DP several times. With some probability it works.

It does not help now, though (when I see 4 lanes instead of 2).

What can I do to solve this? Is it a problem with signal coming from the video card?

Drivers version: Linux x64 **375.82**

There is also a projector connected via HDMI as the 4th monitor.

#### Full screen map:

[image: Screen map]

Comment: Considered possibility of faulty cable? Have you tried to swap cables?

Comment: Yes, tried. No difference.

Comment: What happens if you try `nouveau` instead of the closed-source `nvidia` driver? Anyway, help with the closed-source driver should probably be provided via the Nvidia website - and if it's a bug, they are the ones that need to know.

Comment: In fact, one contact on the cable looks damaged. I have just noticed it, but it does not make much difference. I will try nouveau later either. Thanks, I am going to post it on Nvidia dev forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by buying a DisplayPort cable (not mini).
Maybe the interface on the monitor was damaged.